# How do we solve $\sin(\sin(x))=a$?

Tags: trigonometry

While I was solving a sum, I got stuck at how to go further when I incurred
$\sin(\sin(x^2))=1$ or $0$, where $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
Can someone help me to proceed this step and also a general way of approaching $\sin(\sin(x))$ type problems?

Comment: firstly notice $a$ is bounded by $-sin(1),sin(1)$ , then its just basic inverse, so for $1$ it's not possible as it's outside bounds as for $0$ solution is $sin(x^2)=0$

Comment: Please let the title match the content.

Comment: So sin(sinx^2)=1 is out of bounds right? X^2=arcsin(1.57) is not possible. Correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**:

You can invert a relation like $$v=\sin(u)$$ with $$u=\arcsin(v)+2k\pi\lor u=\pi-\arcsin(v)+2k\pi.$$

Use the trick once to get $\sin(x^2)$ and a second time to get $x^2$.

---

Notice that the value of the sine is limited to the range $[-1,1]$, and as it is monotonous there,

$$\sin(\sin(t))\in[-\sin(1),\sin(1)]$$ and there are no solutions for $a$ outside this range. ($\sin(1)\approx0.841471$)

Answer (score -2):

draw graphs of `sin(x)` and `arcsin(a)`.
the solution will be the intersection point of these two graphs.

Comment: By this approach you could miss some solutions, as the sine isn't invertible.

Comment: Sine isn't invertible.... I don't understand?

Comment: It isn't an injective function. $y=\sin(x)$ and $x=\arcsin(y)$ aren't equivalent.

Comment: Thnxs for clearing the confusion.. I always used this method to do such type of calculation , will take care about it in future.